# A doubt with the concept of quotient topology/quotient map

Tags: general-topology

I am stuck with a minor concept related to the quotient map.

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $q:X\to Y$ be a surjective function. Using this function, we define the quotient topology $\tau'$ on a space $Y$ as $$\tau'=\{B\subseteq Y | q^{-1}(B)\in\tau\}.$$ Thus, $q:X\to Y$ has been termed a "quotient map".

Now, in the material that I have been following, I came across the following theorem related to quotient maps:

> *Theorem:* Let $q:X\to Y $ be a quotient map. Suppose $f:X\to Z$ is a continuous map such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, whenever $q(x_1)=q(x_2)$. Then, there exists a unique map $\hat{f}:Y\to Z$ such that $\hat{f}\circ q=f$.

While the continuity itself was not hard to understand from the proof, the existence and uniqueness of such an "extension" or function as $\hat{f}$ has been called "obvious". I'd appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: The given equation tells you how to define the map and why it is unique. Consider an element $y\in Y$, there exists an $x\in X$ so that $q(x) = y$, now what does the equation tell you?

Comment: Note that the existence of $\hat f$ (as explained by @JustinYoung) depends on the assumed property  of $f$ that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ whenever $q(x_1)=q(x_2)$.

Comment: Right, so $\hat{f}(y)=\hat{f}(q(x))$, for some $x\in X$, which is equal to $h(q(x))=h(y)$, if I am to consider $h$ as another "extension"/"factor" of the function $f$.  @JustinYoung

Comment: It makes sense now. Thanks to both of you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $\hat{f} \circ q = f$ that you need to satisfy actually *defines* the map too so it's clearly unique. If $y \in Y$, by surejctiveness of $q$ we can find some $x \in X$ such that $q(x)=y$ and then taking $\hat{f}$ on both sides gives $\hat{f}(y)=f(x)$. The value $x$ does not matter because if $x'$ would also satisfy $q(x')=y$ the condition on $f$ actually implies $f(x)=f(x')$ so that $\hat{f}(y)$ does *not* depend on the point we chose as preimage (well-definedness) and the preimage exists so $\hat{f}$ is defined on all of $Y$.